# Angular force a readonly text input to submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit, readonly

I have a readonly text input that I want to submit.

I want to preset the value in the form and have it stay there so the form could be resubmit.

How do you do this using Angular?   P.S. it's not disabled, checked will be true.

```
                        <tr ng-repeat="param in paramList">
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="paramName"
                                               class="hidden_text ng-not-empty ng-touched"
                                               ng-model="mycommand.paramNames[$index]"
                                               ng-value="param.name"
                                               ng-disabled="!checked" />
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

set

```
 ng-disabled="true"
```

then it will be disabled as check is undefined or if checked is defined then it will be

```
 ng-disabled="{{!param.checked}}"
```